# ASP - Core Migrate EF Core SQL DB on Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to have my ASP Core Web API ensure the DB is migrated to the latest migration using EF Core?  I know this can be done through the command line, but I want to do it programatically.

Comment: still not done it should be implemented with the next version. You can use the workaround which is posted below from Khan.

Comment: See the answers below. You should use either EnsureCreated or Migrate. Not both.

Comment: Official documentation says : 'Don't call EnsureCreated() before Migrate(). EnsureCreated() bypasses Migrations to create the schema and cause Migrate() to fail.' : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#applying-migrations-at-runtime

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use

```
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

to get your db up to date with your current model. If you want to enable migrations (If subsequent migrations are suspected), then use

```
db.Database.Migrate();
```

and put your subsequent migrations over time.

Comment: EnsureCreated() is working fine But  "context.Database.Migrate() " there is no Migrate() method  why is that ? EF Core

Comment: @Floxy I think you're missing `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`.

Comment: @Michael  Yes!! i  forgot to mention that Thank anyway !! <3

Comment: Where is the right place to call `Database.Migrate` in an ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: @Shimmy it should be placed in the `Configure` method. And will look something like this

`context.Database.Migrate();` and you would inject the `DbContext` to the `Configure` method

Answer (score 58):

A note from documentation on the call to `db.Database.EnsureCreated()`:

> Note that this API does not use migrations to create the database. In
> addition, the database that is created cannot be later updated using
> migrations. If you are targeting a relational database and using
> migrations, you can use the DbContext.Database.Migrate() method to
> ensure the database is created and all migrations are applied.

You may just want to call `db.Database.Migrate()`.

Comment taken from source found above declaration [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/DatabaseFacade.cs#L70).

Answer (score 33):

Use below code to run migration at

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourContext`enter code here`>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

Comment: After upgrading from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.0 (and implicitly from out-of-process hosting to in-process hosting), calling `Migrate` from the startup stopped working for me. The web app just wouldn't boot without error message. I had mark the project as `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` and then it worked again.

Answer (score 20):

Based on the answer of @steamrolla I would propose the following improvement:

```
public static class EnsureMigration
{
    public static void EnsureMigrationOfContext<T>(this IApplicationBuilder app) where T:DbContext
    {
        var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<T>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

With this you can also ensure the migration of different contexts, e.g. if you have a Identity database.

Usage:

```
app.EnsureMigrationOfContext<context>();
```

Answer (score 18):

This works for me in ASP.NET Core 3.1, simply injecting the db context as a parameter to the existing `Configure` method after registering it in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite("Data Source=LocalDatabase.db"));

    ...
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
{
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();

    ...
}
```

More details and links to full code samples available at https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/12/27/aspnet-core-automatic-ef-core-migrations-to-sql-database-on-startup

Comment: This works if you only have one or few contexts. But if you have many contexts there should be another way

Comment: It works with multiple contexts as well. I use it in a project with multiple contexts that inherit from a single base context - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/14/aspnet-core-3-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management

Comment: I mean it's not very convenient to add multiple context parameters in the `Configure()` method. I followed the `IStartupFilter` approach to get migration automatically done on app startup.

Comment: Only a single context parameter is required in the `Configure()` method - https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-registration-login-api/blob/master/Startup.cs#L90

It maps to a different concrete type depending on the environment - https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-registration-login-api/blob/master/Startup.cs#L33-L36

Comment: Ok I see. Your use case is different. You only have 1 context but with two different forms. I think that's a special behavior. In general speaking, one would like to automatically migrate all datacontexts within an application on app startup. For instance, we currently have 9 datacontexts connecting to 4 different databases (all SQL server).

Comment: Ah yep that's a different use case

Answer (score 6):

I followed the `IStartupFilter` approach to have a generic way for migrating any context.

```
 public class DataContextAutomaticMigrationStartupFilter<T> : IStartupFilter
  where T : DbContext
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        return app =>
        {
            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>().Database.SetCommandTimeout(160);
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>().Database.Migrate();
            }
            next(app);
        };
    }
}
```

Now we're able to register the DataContexts and migration in the following way:

1st context

```
 services.AddDbContext<ConsumerDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ConsumerConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, DataContextAutomaticMigrationStartupFilter<ConsumerDataContext>>();
```

2nd context

```
services.AddDbContext<UserDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("UserConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, DataContextAutomaticMigrationStartupFilter<UserDataContext>>();
```

..and so on..

The culprit of `IStartupFilter` is that it only allows synchronous execution of code. For database migrations this is not an issue since we have a synchronous `Migrate()` method.

Comment: `.SetCommandTimeout(160);` is that temporary or will that persist?

Comment: @sommmen While reading the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.setcommandtimeout?view=efcore-6.0) this settings is persistent throughout the DbContext.

Comment: i thought so - in that case perhaps its not good te set it here by default in that case...

Comment: @sommmen feel free to modify code samples according to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

In ASP.NET Core 6 you won't have a `Startup.cs` file. In previous version you had the `Configure` method wich allowed you to access `ServiceProvider` directly and then use `GetService` method to get the Context instance and finally call the `Migrate` method.

In ASP.NET Core 6 you should create a scope and resolve it out of that scope.

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: using (var Scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<KyloDbContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}

Answer (score 5):

Based on chintan310's answer, here is how I migrate the database. This ensures separation of database-related tasks into `Program.cs`:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var context = services.GetService<AppDbContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();

                var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppSeeder>();
                seeder.Seed().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 5):

This code works in .NET core 3.0

```
 using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
 {
     var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
     dbContext.Database.Migrate();
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting .NET Core 2 using C# 7.1, you can have an asynchronous `Main` method to your app,  so you can call all initialization logic before you run the host, right after it has finished building:

```cs
public class Program
{
  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
    //first build
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    //initialize
    using (var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
      var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
      var isDevelopment = 
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().IsDevelopment();

      using var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();


      if (isDevelopment)
        await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
      else
        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

      if (isDevelopment)
      {
        using var userManager = 
          serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
        await userManager
          .CreateAsync(new AppUser { UserName = "dummy", Email = "dummy@dumail.com" },
          password: "1234");
      }
    }

    //now run
    host.Run();
  }

  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
      {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In EF Core 7 you can do it in `Program.cs`  right after `var app = builder.Build();` this way :

```
using (var Scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Happy coding and don't forget **Up Vote** ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a slight correction to the previous answer which created an extension method. It fixes the error that is thrown the way it was written.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyApp.Extensions
{
    public static class IApplicationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void SyncMigrations<T>(this IApplicationBuilder app) where T : DbContext
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this approach, just small correction, there should be `var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<T>();` instead of `<DbContext>`

Answer (score 1):

I did this to migrate programmatically with EF Core 2.1.2 & SQL Server, based on previous answers here and [bailando bailando's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263675/843984) on "[How and where to call Database.EnsureCreated and Database.Migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238043/how-and-where-to-call-database-ensurecreated-and-database-migrate)":

**Startup.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // ... (only relevant code included) ...

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAppContext")));
            // ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyAppContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The project using this code is [available at Github](https://github.com/lauriharpf/cocktails/tree/987c22749f9acaf23f867d1f7eec27fafc964064).