# After AddDbContext now I want tu use my context

Tags: entity-framework-core

I decided to use this AddDbContext method to add and setup my context for my Entity Framework Core project.

```
services.AddDbContext<ExampleContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleConnection"))); 
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970589/196526
```

I suppose this `AddDbContext` allow us to add a global context and it is possible to retrieve it later when required in my controller or service class. How can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, dotnet core has got dependency injection inbuilt now. The way you use it in your controllers, service or repository classes is as simple as through a constructor injection.

Example -

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository{
   private readonly DbContext _exampleContext;
 public AccountRepository(ExampleContext context){
   _exampleContext = context;
}
```

}

Comment: You can also retrieve it from the ServiceProvider with IServiceProvider.GetService<ExampleContext>()