# Retrieve the context in oData controller

Tags: entity-framework-core, odata

I decided to use this AddDbContext method to add and setup my context for my Entity Framework Core project using ODataController

```
services.AddDbContext<ExampleContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleConnection"))); 
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970589/196526
```

I suppose this `AddDbContext` allow us to add a global context and it is possible to retrieve it later when required in my controller or service class. How can I use it?

At this moment I pass my context each time.

public class StudentsController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly ExampleContext _context;

```
    public StudentsController(ExampleContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

I would like to get load my context without having to pass it to my controller. I'm using ODataController.

Comment: *without having to pass it to my controller* -- But that's the whole idea of dependency injection. If you don't do it this way you'll revert to the less recommended service locator pattern. Also, using a global context is a bad idea.

Comment: If you don't wish to pass it trough the constructor you could use the [FromServices attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute).