# Entity Framework Core Update Database - Code First Approach Without Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api2

I've been searching for a way, it may or may not be supported yet, I guess I'm looking for a concrete answer.

What I've been looking for is the solution for the following requirements:

- EFCore Code First Approach
- With existing database table with significant amount of data already in place
- Add a couple of columns to the said database table by updating my model
- No migrations through PM Console, just using Context with Fluent Api at application start
- No database recreation
- The approach can be: Check a configuration file or some sort, compare it against the version in a version table in database to trigger the update
- Project templates: Web Api 2, Uwp

If this is supported, is it advisable? If not, why? what are the disadvantages?

In my experience with the projects I was part of, either database first approach or code first but with database recreation.

The steps I have in mind are:
 - Update the model
 - Create migration objects
 - Update config file for db version
 - At application start, check the config version against version table
 - If versions do not match call Update() or Migrate() or both, with Migration objects/types as parameters

Comment: what you should do is create everything in your model of your existing db. fake the migration table information. then add any migrations to revise your database.

Comment: So you really need the migrations? These can't all be achieved at application start or something like that?

Comment: you can invoke migrations at startup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780136/asp-core-migrate-ef-core-sql-db-on-startup

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try those, but I remember I already did, but will try again. But this should work with Uwp and Web api 2, right?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite opinion based, but here are my comments.

> EFCore Code First Approach

Are you aware of <s>limitations of EF Core? It's linq provider cannot do everything EF6 does.</s> [differences between EF and EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/)?

> With existing database table with significant amount of data already in place

That's OK.

> Add a couple of columns to the said database table by updating my model

This seems standard practice for EF (Core) apps.

> No migrations through PM Console, just using Context with Fluent Api at application start

I don't recommend automatic db upgrades because of the risks of the migration done not when you want it. I'd call it accidental-updagrade-database.

> No database recreation

I'm not sure what this means, but yes, EF (Core) can work without recreating a db.

> The approach can be: Check a configuration file or some sort, compare it against the version in a version table in database to trigger the update
>
> Project templates: Web Api 2, Uwp

The Uwp part seems irrelevant as I assume that all db access will be done via the api app.

Comment: Thanks! this is insightful. Yup I'm aware that there are limitations in efcore compared to ef6, will have to recheck what are those. Project templates I mentioned are maybe irrelevant, maybe more of fyi, as I have a separate library for data access. I'll remove the tags.

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT, not really, but this answer is helpful. I guess I'm asking a vague question. Let me try again, I want to have a solution for my Data Access to automatically update my DB when I added a property to my Model, why automatic? because I don't want migration histories in my solution. I know automatic migration exists, but haven't had success doing so in even with a simple project, maybe I haven't found the right guide I'm looking for. But based on tymtam's answer automatic db-upgrade is not recommended. Anyway, this is just a side thought I have while working on personal project.