# Is there a way to ensure db migrations in entity framework core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Is there a way similar to `Database.EncureCreated()` method to ensure all migrations were executed from the app?

Comment: [db.Database.Migrate();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_Migrate_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP - Core Migrate EF Core SQL DB on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780136/asp-core-migrate-ef-core-sql-db-on-startup)

Comment: Check the following link to use the `context.Database.Migrate()` or `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` method: [auto create database in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/auto-create-database-in-entity-framework-core) and [EF Core Seeding](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Database.Migrate()` - [REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-3.1)

From the article:

> Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database. Will create the database if it does not already exist.

Note that `Database.Migrate()` is mutually exclusive with `Database.EnsureCreated()`